# angular configure hot reload / live reload for speed

Tags: angular, angular-cli, livereload, hot-reload

I'm using Angular 5.

The hot reload takes about 8 secs which is reasonable (not great though) but is there any way to configure it so I can tweak it to make it faster?

Concerned it will get even slower as the app grows. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to compile with Ahead-of-Time option

[Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler): With AOT, the browser downloads a pre-compiled version of the application. The browser loads executable code so it can render the application immediately, without waiting to compile the app first.

Comment: Using aot increased the hot reload time in my case.  `ng serve --aot`